# TimerJob object update method object already exists

Tags: development, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

Trying to execute the Update method on a `SPJobDefinition` object, I notice that it recall the "empty Constructor" and returns me the following error:

> An object of the type SendMailDaily.SendMailDaily named
>   "SendMailDaily" already exists under the parent
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication
>   named "".  Rename your object or delete the existing object.

Code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("Begin");
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                SPSite site =  parentWebApp.Sites[0];
                //DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
                CreateConfigList(site);
                CreateJob(parentWebApp);
            });
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("Errore:" + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
    private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
    {
        bool jobCreated = false;
        try
        {
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("Begin");
            SendMailDaily job = new SendMailDaily(JobName, site);
            SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
            //schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
            //schedule.EndSecond = 59;
            //schedule.Interval = 15;
            job.Schedule = schedule;

            job.Update();
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("End");
            return jobCreated;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            loggerObjFeature.writeLog("Errore:" + ex.Message);
            return jobCreated;
        }

    }
```

Comment: where do you use this code? Please provide some more details

Comment: code Updated. I'm using it into the feature activation

Answer (score 0):

Try to define this constructor:

```
public SendMailDaily SPWebApplication application)
    : base(JobName, application, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
{

}
```

and then use it:

```
SendMailDaily job = new SendMailDaily(site);
```

instead of

```
SendMailDaily job = new SendMailDaily(JobName, site);
```